# display inside a column the number from a string

Tags: excel

I have one column (B) ( over 3k cells ):

```
TestUrl
__________________________________
http://www.testing.eu/test123.html

http://www.testing.eu/test154.html

http://www.testing.eu/test983.html

.. and so on ...
```

I want in column C, to get only the numbers:

```
Numbers
__________
123

154

983

..and so on..
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: All texts start with `http://www.testing.eu/test` and end with `.html`?

Comment: Yes, the only 'thing' which differs is the number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using formula in column B:

```
=MID(A1,LEN("http://www.testing.eu/test") + 1, LEN(A1) - LEN(".html") - LEN("http://www.testing.eu/test"))
```

Using VBA and Regex:

```
Sub GetNumberFromURL()
    Dim regEx As Object, matches As Object, cl As Range

    Set regEx = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

    regEx.Pattern = "([0-9]+)"

    For Each cl In Range("A1:A10") //Update to suit your needs

        Set matches = regEx.Execute(cl)
        cl.Offset(0, 1) = matches.Item(0)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks, btw: How can I sort ascending easily column B based on the number contained in the URL?

Comment: Not sure what you mean? If you have just the number in column B and then highlight columns A and B and then choose to sort ascending by column B then this will get all the URLs sorted as per the number that has been stripped out

Answer (score 1):

using an array formula.. 
assuming your data starts at B2.
type this in the formula bar on C2.
Then instead of pressing ENTER, press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER.
Then just drag down to copy to other cells below.

=SUMPRODUCT(MID(0&**B2**,LARGE(INDEX(ISNUMBER(--MID(**B2**,ROW($1:$50),1))* ROW($1:$50),0),ROW($1:$50))+1,1)*10^ROW($1:$50)/10)

change the B2 in the formula if your data starts somwhere else. Just make sure to press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER instead of ENTER after changing.

got this from:
http://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1622-excel-extract-number-from-string.html

Comment: of the first C column data you have?

Comment: assuming your first data is in B2, then copy this in C2 and press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER.

Comment: updated coz it wont work on string with more than 20 characters. should work now.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the B column data in notepad and replace http://www.testing.eu/test by empty string and then do same thing with .html. After replacing/removing these string paste the notepad content in column C

Comment: You could do this in Excel using `find & replace` but I get the gist of your approach...